# Quartz Jobs overlapping

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a few quartz (2.2) Jobs running. Let's say one is running ever 5 seconds, another on runs every 10 mins.

I don't want 2 jobs to be executed the same time. I've seen this

```
DisallowConcurrentExecution
```

but this only applies to jobs from the same instance but I generally don't want two jobs (of any instance) to overlap.

**Edit:**
All the jobs working with one database, so this is why it's important that they don't run the same time. Each job has different things to do.

Comment: Two instances on one server? Clustered? How many scheduler instances (you should have only 1 in a cluster)? Thre's a lot of information missing, without which ahswering the question is difficult.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to Quartz, sorry for that. Quartz is running within a Java  App on one server. No clusting or so.
Each Job has it's own trigger as the jobs have different times the should run (as said every 5 seconds, every hour and so on) (See my edits)

Comment: So why do you need to run two instances?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand you. But as I understood one job has an execution method. This is unique to this job. I my case. I have different jobs, doing different rollups within the database. These are completely different tasks..

Comment: Do you have any level of precedence between the two jobs or is it irrelevant? For instance,  in case of simultaneous execution, you only want the 10 mins. job to run.

Comment: Yeah, The least important is the one running every 2 seconds. Then it's the one running each hour (Then there are 2 others running every 12 hours and running every 24 hours) But it would be the best way to just wait for any job for a free slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to configure the underlying thread pool to use one thread, this will achieve your goal. Add the following property to your quartz.properties configuration file:

**org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount**

> The number of threads available for
>   concurrent execution of jobs. You can specify any positive integer,
>   although only numbers between 1 and 100 are practical. If you only
>   have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then one thread is
>   plenty. If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many firing every
>   minute, then you want a thread count more like 50 or 100 (this highly
>   depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform, and your
>   systems resources).